# Android studio menu item

Tags: android, xml

I am relative new to Android and I've been getting this error "Menu items should specify a title" even though I have the item title clearly defined below, strange error that has very confused, anyone know what the problem may be?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/Add_New">

</item>
```

Comment: Make sure that you have a closing menu tag at the end of your file: `</menu>`.

Comment: Yeah I have that there, I didn't highlight it during copy and paste by accident, thanks though!

Comment: Are you using `appcompat-v7:21` backward compatibility lib?

Comment: How would I check that? In build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, but If you ask that is probably that you aren't using this lib...

Comment: I have this in my build.gradle:   "dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}"

Comment: Try to use `app:title` instead of `android:title`.

Comment: That didn't work either unfortunately, thank you so much for trying though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a wrong XML namespace!
Try with:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</menu>
```

And as G.T. suggested you should consider using appcompat on the `showAsAction` property (only needed if you want to support API < 11):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/Add_New" />
</menu>
```

Note:

*The appcompat library is compatible with some old Android versions (API 7+) that can't handle the `showAsAction` property because they don't have the `ActionBar` (API < 11).*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/item1" 
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:title="@string/Add_New" 
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
</item>
</menu>
```

It works for me perfectly.

Comment: I can't see what you added to my answer.